# aws amplify update my Vuex state on DynamoDB table update using triggers

Tags: vue.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS amplify with my Vue.js application which has a player state that stores player data from the player table from the GraphQL API. I'd like to update the state on player data update in table by using triggers or subscriptions. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscription provided by AppSync GraphQL. It will handle DynamoDB trigger itself.

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
import { onUpdatePlayer } from "../../graphql/subscriptions";
```

Here's Reactjs specific code

```
const PlayerComponent = () => {
  let subscriptionOnUpdate;

  const setupSubscriptions = () => {
    subscriptionOnUpdate = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onUpdatePlayer)
    ).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        // do stuff like updating other state 
      },
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setupSubscriptions();

    return () => {
      subscriptionOnUpdate.unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can this also be modified to handle direct data updates to the DyanamoDB? I've implemented it but it seems there is no response when I directly update the table from the browser

Comment: Not sure about that, I've used it for showing/notifying new post on newsfeed without refreshing.

Comment: Direct update, you mean from AWS Console?

Comment: Yes. So, what I want is to watch the DyanamoDB such that when the table is modified from the console, the subscription is triggered

Comment: I don't think subscription will trigger unless the record is added by GraphQL mutation. Check out this documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-data.html

Comment: I guess in that case you can use Lambda function that sends GraphQL mutation

Comment: That is the solution I've been thinking about, actually, I can use it with DyanamoDB streams, but I don't know how to implement it, do you have any experience with lambda functions and implementing them in React or Vue?